# Android: practical example of START_STICKY and START_REDELIVER_INTENT

Tags: android, service

I can think of a practical example when to use `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`: suppose our music player is playing music, and if our service is killed due to lack of memory, then we want it to restart playing when memory is available. For that we can use `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, because we are sending the id/path of track we need to play in the intent which started the service and we will need same intent again to play same track when service is restarted.

But, in many places it is mentioned that we need to use `START_STICKY` with a music player. I am unable to understand why they have mentioned `START_STICKY` as we need to know the path/id of track to start playing it again. Can anyone give a practical example when we need to use `START_STICKY`?

Comment: I improved the question to make it clearer, and mentioned Android in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time START_STICKY used because if service want to run in background even if app is killed or stopwithTask and we can stop it as needed.

While START_REDELIVER_INTENT used for are used for services that should only remain running while processing any commands sent to them.

Comment: Can you please explain?I don't think START_STICKY and START_REDELIVER_INTENT is related to stopping service but they only differentiate in redelivering intent when service restarts